# Restore window without setting to foreground

Tags: python, winapi, hwnd

I can only take an image of a non-iconic (not minimized) window, so if I see one I restore it, but then it pops to the foreground. Right now I have this solution:

```
if win32gui.IsIconic(hwnd):
    active_hwnd= win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_RESTORE)
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(active_hwnd)
```

but sometimes the flickering is interrupting other running processes. How can I restore a window, and set it to be the last in the windows z-order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a search in win32 i found this solution:

```
if win32gui.IsIconic(hwnd):
        win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, win32con.SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

[SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) sets the Z order. Use it with HWND_BOTTOM.